# Switch: использование фигурных скобок в case перед break

Tags: java, android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.start:
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(this, Menu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            break;  
        case R.id.records: 
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, RecordList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;   
    }
}
```

В обработке первой кнопки есть фигурные скобки, хотел бы понять как они в данном случае работают. Если их убрать, то будет жалоба на то, что два одинаковых названия `intent`, пусть даже стоит оператор `break`. Если я вдруг напишу такой код, что первая кнопка не будет переходить по созданному интенту и у меня будет возможность кликнуть и по второй кнопке, то что-то нехорошее произойдет.

Comment: интересная реализация) совет не по существу вопроса: вынесите `Intent = new Intent()` и `startActivity(intent)` за пределы `switch`. Если он там у вас все равно повторяется

Comment: ну в данном случае ваше решение верно, но у меня  в `switch` есть еще кнопки, где вообще интент не создается, например кнопка выхода, вдруг я нажму на кнопку, где интент не нужен. Хотя учитывая, что кнопок, вероятность нажатия на кнопки, где будет создан интент выше, то можно и вынести.

Comment: ну я делаю проверку `if (intent!=null) startActivity(intent)`. А вообще - в ответе нормально написали как можно сделать)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{ ... }` в данном случае - это просто (анонимный) блок кода. И сделано это, видимо, только для того, чтобы не было конфликта имён переменных.

---

В [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1563039/3432401) говорится, что использование таких блоков - это зачастую признак плохо написанного кода. Утверждение, конечно, можно считать спорным, но конкретно в этом случае создание `Intent`-а, а также вызовы методов `setClass` и `startActivity` можно вынести из `switch`-а, оставив в `case`-ах только выбор класса:

```
Class clazz = null;
switch (v.getId())
{
    case R.id.start:
        clazz = Menu.class;
        break;  
    case R.id.records: 
        clazz = RecordList.class;
        break;   
}
if (clazz != null)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, clazz);
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Comment: Мой комментарий написанный Jarvis_J под вопросом, относится и к тому, что вы говорите.  А вот меня больше интересовало, то что это анонимный блок кода. С некоторыми вещами в java  я не очень знаком.

Comment: @Turalllb лично я все годы написания кода на Java вполне обходился без таких блоков. Это не значит, что их не надо использовать вообще, но всё же. Если в `case`-ах разные действия, то чтобы не связываться с анонимными блоками кода, можно в качестве альтернативы использовать: 1. `if-else`; 2. Вынос тел `case`-ов в отдельные методы; 3. Вынос обработки в отдельные классы (кнопка <-> обработчик кнопки) и замена `switch`-a на выбор нужного обработчика. Что считать из этого хорошим подходом - дело субъективное, плюс зависит от конкретной ситуации.

Comment: Да я вас понял, в коде практически не попадались анонимные блоки и выглядят они не очень читабельно. Просто, чтобы знать, да и инетрвьюверы любят всякие такие бесполезные для практики, задачки

Answer (score 2):

Пара фигурных скобок `{...}` задает границы **блока** кода. В Java переменные можно объявлять в любом блоке. Блок определяет **область действия (видимости)** переменных. В вашем примере три области видимости переменных (даже 4, если считать поля класса) вложенные друг в друга.

```
public void onClick(View v) {// область 1
     switch (v.getId()) {// область 2
         case R.id.start:{//область 3
         }
     }
}
```

В таком случае переменные, объявленные в области 1 доступны из области 2 и 3, переменные обхявленные в области 2 будут доступны в области 3, но не доступны в области 1. Однако перемынные из области 3 недоступны за пределом этой области. Например следующий код не скомпилируется пока не закомментируете строку 22, т.к переменная в этом месте уже не доступна

```
public class FieldVisiblTester { 
    //область1 - поля класса, видимы везде внутри класса
    String s1 = "string1";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FieldVisiblTester().method();
    }

    void method(){ 
        //область2 - локальные переменные метода, видимы внутри метода
        String s2 = "string2";
        { //область3 - переменные блока кода, видимы внутри блока
            String s3 = "string3";
            System.out.println("inside code block");
            System.out.println(s1);
            System.out.println(s2);
            System.out.println(s3);
        }
        System.out.println("inside method");
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
        //переменная s3 недоступна вне блока, где она объявлена
        System.out.println(s3); 

    }
}
```

Ошибка

> FieldVisiblTester.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
>                   System.out.println(s3);
>
> symbol:   variable s3   location: class FieldVisiblTester 1 error

Еще интересный момент - в Java нельзя "скрывать/перекрывать" переменные блоком кода. Следующий код не скомпилируется (error: variable s2 is already defined in method method())

```
void method(){ 
    //область2 - локальные переменные метода, видимы внутри метода
    String s2 = "string2";
    { //область3 - переменные блока кода, видимы внутри блока
      // т.к s2 объявлена в "наружном" блоке, она видима и тут
      // т.е нельзя использовать то же имя 
        String s2 = "string3";
    }

}
```

Но можно сделать так

```
void method(){ 
    {
        String s2 = "string3";
    }
    //вышли из блока кода, переменная s2 не видима
    //можно объявить еще раз
    String s2 = "string2";
}
```

Comment: на счет последнего куска кода: переменная s2 невидима или же просто ушла в небытие и её скоро пожнет сборщик мусора? Имею ввиду, поля в блоке кода теряют ссылки, после того как блок кода завершен, так ведь?

Comment: Если говорить о конкретно этом примере, то ссылка на объект больше не существует и сам объект можно отдать сборщику мусора. Но нужно понимать, что в блоке кода например можно положить обект String в массив строк, тогда после выхода из блока, сам объект строки уничтожать нельзя, т.к. ссылка на него все еще осталась в массиве. Еще при работе со String следует учесть использование String constant pool.